# USB HID Device only reporting first event

Tags: linux, usb, hid

I have a eDIO USB Multi Remote Controller( a Infrared Reciever) that came with ASUS PSR 2000 Web Surfing Remote Control.

I am trying to connect the Remote COntroller to my pi so that it recieves the keystrokes sent by the remote.

The controller is detected as a HID device. Here are the details from the lsusb -v command

```
Bus 001 Device 007: ID 147a:e001 Formosa Industrial Computing, Inc.
Couldn't open device, some information will be missing
Device Descriptor:
bLength                18
bDescriptorType         1
bcdUSB               1.10
bDeviceClass            0 (Defined at Interface level)
bDeviceSubClass         0
bDeviceProtocol         0
bMaxPacketSize0         8
idVendor           0x147a Formosa Industrial Computing, Inc.
idProduct          0xe001
bcdDevice            1.22
iManufacturer           1
iProduct                2
iSerial                 0
bNumConfigurations      1
Configuration Descriptor:
bLength                 9
bDescriptorType         2
wTotalLength           34
bNumInterfaces          1
bConfigurationValue     1
iConfiguration          4
bmAttributes         0xa0
(Bus Powered)
Remote Wakeup
MaxPower              300mA
Interface Descriptor:
bLength                 9
bDescriptorType         4
bInterfaceNumber        0
bAlternateSetting       0
bNumEndpoints           1
bInterfaceClass         3 Human Interface Device
bInterfaceSubClass      1 Boot Interface Subclass
bInterfaceProtocol      2 Mouse
iInterface              0
HID Device Descriptor:
bLength                 9
bDescriptorType        33
bcdHID               1.10
bCountryCode            0 Not supported
bNumDescriptors         1
bDescriptorType        34 Report
wDescriptorLength      20
Report Descriptors:
 ** UNAVAILABLE **
 Endpoint Descriptor:
 bLength                 7
bDescriptorType         5
bEndpointAddress     0x81  EP 1 IN
bmAttributes            3
  Transfer Type            Interrupt
  Synch Type               None
  Usage Type               Data
wMaxPacketSize     0x0004  1x 4 bytes
bInterval              10
```

I can also the device in the dev folder with an event created

```
pi@raspberrypi /dev/input/by-id $ dir
usb-Cypress_Semiconductor_eDio_USB_Multi_Remote_Controlle-event-if00
```

The event handler associated with it is as follows as seen from the following command.

```
    pi@raspberrypi /proc/bus/input $ cat devices
    I: Bus=0003 Vendor=147a Product=e001 Version=0110
    N: Name="Cypress Semiconductor eDio USB Multi Remote Controlle"
    P: Phys=usb-bcm2708_usb-1.2/input0
    S: Sysfs=/devices/platform/bcm2708_usb/usb1/1-1/1-1.2/1-1.2:1.0/input/input2
    U: Uniq=
    H: Handlers=event0
    B: PROP=0
    B: EV=1
```

The problem is when I am trying to read the output from the event handler created for the device.The first keystroke is registered but the subsequent key strokes are not displayed by the CAT command.

```
   pi@raspberrypi /dev/input $ cat event0 | xxd
   0000000: e007 9450 9476 0900 0000 0000 0000 0000  ...P.v..........
```

Please suggest me what can I do to get the device working. Pressing any keys after the first keystroke doesn't return anything unless the device is replugged.

Please suggest what needs to be done to fix the issue.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on what you ultimately want to do, mapping the buttons of the HID remote to keystrokes might be enough and is fairly easy to achieve with tools such as [QJoyPad](http://qjoypad.sourceforge.net/).

That seems [hard to build on a Raspberry Pi](http://www.raspberrypi.org/phpBB3/viewtopic.php?t=26178&p=237981), so you might want to try [joy2key](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Joy2key) instead, which is available in the repos: `sudo apt-get install joy2key`.

Answer (score 1):

Finally I got time to write my own implementation using the PyUSB library which is a wrapper for Libusb.

I am posting the code here.Might help someone.

I have another piece of code that creates the configuration file which is used here.Haven't mapped all the remote keys since I don't need all of them.

```
import usb.core
import usb.util
import ConfigParser
import shlex
import subprocess
import logging

# find our device
diction={
  6402315641282315:'1',
  6402415641282415:'2',
  6402515641282515:'3',
  6402615641282615:'4',
  6402715641282715:'5',
  6402815641282815:'6',
  6402915641282915:'7',
  6403015641283015:'8',
  6403115641283115:'9',
  }



def load_config():
    dict={}
    config = ConfigParser.RawConfigParser()
    config.read('/codes/remote/remote.cfg')

    dict['vendor']=config.getint('Settings','idVendor')

    dict['product']=config.getint('Settings','idProduct')

    dict['interface']=config.getint('Settings', 'interface')

    r=config.options('Key Mappings')

    for item in r:
        if config.get('Key Mappings',item)!='': 
            dict[item]=config.get('Key Mappings',item)
            #print config.get('Key Mappings',item)
    return dict

def pyus():

    try:
        load_log()
        dict=load_config()
        join_int = lambda nums: int(''.join(str(i) for i in nums))
        #print dict

        dev = usb.core.find(idVendor=dict['vendor'], idProduct=dict['product'])
        interface=dict['interface']

        if dev is None:
            raise ValueError('Device not found')

        if dev.is_kernel_driver_active(interface) is True:
                #print "but we need to detach kernel driver"
                dev.detach_kernel_driver(interface)
        #dev.detatch_kernel_driver(interface) 
        # set the active configuration. With no arguments, the first
        # configuration will be the active one
        dev.set_configuration()

        # get an endpoint instance
        cfg = dev.get_active_configuration()
        interface_number = cfg[(0,0)].bInterfaceNumber
        alternate_setting = usb.control.get_interface(dev,interface_number)
        intf = usb.util.find_descriptor(
            cfg, bInterfaceNumber = interface_number,
            bAlternateSetting = alternate_setting
        )

        ep = usb.util.find_descriptor(
            intf,
            # match the first IN endpoint
            custom_match = \
            lambda e: \
                usb.util.endpoint_direction(e.bEndpointAddress) == \
                usb.util.ENDPOINT_IN
        )

        assert ep is not None
        #print 'packet details',ep.bEndpointAddress , ep.wMaxPacketSize

        while 1:
            try:
                data = dev.read(ep.bEndpointAddress, ep.wMaxPacketSize*2,interface,1000)
                data=data.tolist()
                key=join_int(data)
                #print "Key is " , key
                if  key in diction:

                    try:
                        args=shlex.split(dict[diction[key]])
                        #print args
                        p=subprocess.Popen(args, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
                        #print "Pressed key is ",diction[key]
                    except:
                        pass


            except usb.core.USBError as e:
                pass
    except:
        pass

pyus()






#____________________________REPORT DESCRIPTOR EXAMPLE___________________
# Bus 001 Device 007: ID 147a:e001 Formosa Industrial Computing, Inc.
    # Couldn't open device, some information will be missing
    # Device Descriptor:
    # bLength                18
    # bDescriptorType         1
    # bcdUSB               1.10
    # bDeviceClass            0 (Defined at Interface level)
   # bDeviceSubClass         0
   # bDeviceProtocol         0
   # bMaxPacketSize0         8
   # idVendor           0x147a Formosa Industrial Computing, Inc.
   # idProduct          0xe001
   # bcdDevice            1.22
   # iManufacturer           1
   # iProduct                2
   # iSerial                 0
   # bNumConfigurations      1
  # Configuration Descriptor:
  # bLength                 9
  # bDescriptorType         2
# wTotalLength           34
# bNumInterfaces          1
# bConfigurationValue     1
# iConfiguration          4
# bmAttributes         0xa0
  # (Bus Powered)
  # Remote Wakeup
# MaxPower              300mA
# Interface Descriptor:
  # bLength                 9
  # bDescriptorType         4
  # bInterfaceNumber        0
  # bAlternateSetting       0
  # bNumEndpoints           1
  # bInterfaceClass         3 Human Interface Device
  # bInterfaceSubClass      1 Boot Interface Subclass
  # bInterfaceProtocol      2 Mouse
  # iInterface              0
    # HID Device Descriptor:
      # bLength                 9
      # bDescriptorType        33
      # bcdHID               1.10
      # bCountryCode            0 Not supported
      # bNumDescriptors         1
      # bDescriptorType        34 Report
      # wDescriptorLength      20
     # Report Descriptors:
       # ** UNAVAILABLE **
  # Endpoint Descriptor:
    # bLength                 7
    # bDescriptorType         5
    # bEndpointAddress     0x81  EP 1 IN
    # bmAttributes            3
      # Transfer Type            Interrupt
      # Synch Type               None
      # Usage Type               Data
    # wMaxPacketSize     0x0004  1x 4 bytes
    # bInterval              10
```